# “EXC_BAD_ACCESS" signal received

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, memory-management

i am beginner in iphone  programming i am doing an app of photo gallery in which while scrolling the UITableView i am getting this exception in my device as Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

can anyone pls help me tackle this problem...

```
enter cod[super viewDidLoad];
self.title=@"Back";

udf=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id_arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
descrip_arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
path_arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
count_arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



client = [[[ClientController alloc] init] autorelease];
r_m = [[[RequestMessage alloc]init] autorelease];
m_j = [[[Main_Json alloc]init] autorelease];

[r_m setServiceType:@"IMAGE"];
[r_m setParameter:@"sample string"];

NSString * json_string = [m_j returnJsonString:r_m:@"button"];
json_string=[json_string stringByAppendingFormat: @"\n"];
NSLog(@"Client is sending:%@", json_string);
//NSLog(json_string);

client.connect; 


NSLog(@"client connecting........");

if([client isConnected])
{
    NSString *flag = [client send:json_string];     
    if(![flag isEqualToString:@"success"])
    {

        NSLog(@"Before Alert_view");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:flag delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    NSString *Var=[client receiveResponse];




    //NSLog(@"TEST:%@",Var);



    NSString *main_str=[Var stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!#{}&" withString:@""];
    //main_str=[Var stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{\"serviceType\":\"ALLIMAGE\",\"parameters\":[[]]}" withString:@""];


    NSLog(@"Split:%@",main_str);





    js=[[JsontoObject alloc]sivajiTV_response:main_str];

    e1=[[Event alloc]init];


    NSLog(@"TEST1:%@",[udf objectForKey:@"id_value"]);
    NSLog(@"TEST2:%@",[udf objectForKey:@"des_value"]);
    NSLog(@"TEST3:%@",[udf objectForKey:@"path_value"]);
    NSLog(@"TEST4:%@",[udf objectForKey:@"count_value"]);


    id_arr=[[udf objectForKey:@"id_value"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray *descrip_arr1 =[[udf objectForKey:@"des_value"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray *path_arr1=[[udf objectForKey:@"path_value"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    count_arr=[[udf objectForKey:@"count_value"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    //NSLog(@"-------------");
    //NSLog(@"STRING_ID2:%@",descrip_arr1);
    //NSLog(@"STRING_ID3:%@",path_arr1);
    //NSLog(@"-------------");

    for (int i=0; i<[descrip_arr1 count]; i++) {
        NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[descrip_arr1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        //NSLog(@"STRING_test:%@",temp);
        temp=[temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
        //NSLog(@"STRING_test1:%@",temp);
        [descrip_arr addObject:temp];

        NSString *temp1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[path_arr1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        temp1=[temp1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
        [path_arr addObject:temp1];
    }


    NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"STRING_ID1:%@",id_arr);
    NSLog(@"STRING_ID2:%@",descrip_arr);
    NSLog(@"STRING_ID3:%@",path_arr);
    NSLog(@"STRING_ID4:%@",count_arr);
    NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    if([main_str isEqualToString: [NSNull null]])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:main_str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }   
}  
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Connection not Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert1 show];
    [alert1 release];

}




UILabel *lblTitle=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];
lblTitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

self.navigationItem.titleView=lblTitle;


toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 25)];
toolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 2, 60, 20)];
mylabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
mylabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
mylabel.text = @"Gallery";
[toolbar addSubview:mylabel];


myTableView.frame=CGRectMake(0,26, 320,430);
//  myTableView.backgroundView=nil;
[self.view addSubview:myTableView];
//self.myTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//UITableViewController *myTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithTableStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
//  UIToolBar *myToolBar = [[UIToolBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 320, 10)];
//  CGRect *toolBarFrame;
//  toolBarFrame = CGMakeRect (0, 440, 320, 40);
//  [toolBarFrame setFrame:toolBarFrame];
//  [myTableViewController.view addSubView:toolBarFrame];
//viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"movies.jpg"]];

//myTableView.rowHeight=120;
[self.view addSubview:myTableView];
//tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sports",@"News",@"naturals1",@"live",nil];
//titleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"SA spinners made the difference: Sammy",@"Cabinet terminates ISRO’s deal",@"Hudson River Fish Evolve Toxic ",@"Hi Today Special News?",nil];
//SBJSON *json = [SBJSON new];
//  json.humanReadable = YES;

//self.tableDataList = tempArray;
//self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//create new uiview with a background image
//UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movies" ofType:@"jpg"]];
//UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];

//adjust the frame for the case of navigation or tabbars
//backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

//add background view and send it to the back
//[self.viewController.view addSubview:backgroundView];
//[self.viewController.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];

//[backgroundView release];

//UIImage *img1= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101216001017.jpg"]]];
//NSLog(@"ERROR1:%@",img1); 

//NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101216001017.jpg"]];
//NSLog(@"ERROR12:%@",imageData);
}
```

Comment: Holy moly... you *really* need to read a good tutorial or book on writing iPhone applications. In particular make sure you read and commit to memory the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Comment: Also, run your code through the static analyser (choose "Build & Analyze"). Let us know what that brings up.

Comment: ya i did... i am getting 14 analyzer results of potential leaks and some values stored are never read..

Comment: can u tell me how to solve dis ..

Comment: To fix the leaks, you need to understand what objects you own and what you don't own. You also need to know what objects you *should* own. If you own an object, you need to relinquish ownership once you are done with it, you can do this by sending either `release` or `autorelease`. If you *don't* own an object, then you *don't* need to send `release` or `autorelease`. Use `retain` properties to help with memory management.

Comment: Remember, to set a property value you must use `self.propertyName = value;`, as this ensures that it will be set using the declared semantics.

Comment: Also, when you compile your code, do you see any warnings? (do a clean before doing a build to make sure all warnings will be printed). Don't ignore warnings, especially if you are getting memory management issues.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many things wrong with your code it is hard to know where to begin:

1. `client.connect;` is syntactic sugar for `[client connect]`, however since `connect` is not a property (at least I *hope* it is not a property), you should *not* use the dot-notation.
2. The argument to `isEqualToString:` expects an `NSString *` object, not `NSNull *`. If you want to see whether the variable points to a string (as opposed to `nil`), or, if you want to make sure that the string actually contains characters, use:

   ```
   if ([main_str length])
       // do something
   ```
3. You assign a new mutable array that you own to `id_arr` using `id_arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`, however you completely overwrite this reference later with `id_arr=[[udf objectForKey:@"id_value"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`. This means that the original array that you created (and own) can no longer be referenced, and is leaked.
4. You never initialise the object that you allocated:

   ```
   js=[[JsontoObject alloc]sivajiTV_response:main_str];
   ```
5. You create an `Event` object, but never use it or release it (this is a memory leak):

   ```
   e1=[[Event alloc]init];
   ```